# Bash - Set grep -rl to return only file name , not full path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, grep

I'm runing a grep to find recursively filenames which files content contain a string.

```
grep -rl string-to-find $pwd
```

The command returns results as expeted, but with file name and path:

```
var/log/httpd/access.log
var/log/httpd/access.log.1
```

How could I set it return only file name not full path?

I would like to get back as result:

```
access.log
access.log.1
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep` has no such flag. But you can pipe its output to a simple `awk` to get your desired output:

```
grep -rl string-to-find $pwd | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'
```

The `-F/` is to set the field separator to `/`,
and `print $NF` means to print the last field.

Comment: I get error "awk: line 2: missing } near end of file"

Comment: @batz crap, I forgot the single quotes around the awk script. Fixed it, try now